# Transform/Distort image the same as in template

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a template mock up file that has an object that has been distorted/ transformed.

I want to take my image and replace the template image.

Is there a way to distort/transform my image to be the same as in the template?

Answer (score 0):

There is a free [script](https://github.com/nvkelso/illustrator-scripts/blob/master/find-and-replace-graphics/findAndReplaceGraphic_transformToFit.jsx) that do what you want:

- Put you new image on top
- select both images and run script
- as a result new object is copied to the position and size of 
  template object.